# Eventlog error id 22 post 512b -> AdvFormat harddrive clone

Tags: windows, windows-vista, event-log

I just cloned Vista from a 512b/sector drive to an Advanced Format 4kb/sector drive. I've fixed all the nightmarish problems that caused except for one, upon which I'm stumped. Every time the system boots, I get an error in the System log:

```
Source: Eventlog
ID: 22
Message: The event logging service encountered an error while initializing 
     publishing resources for channel DebugChannel. If channel type is Analytic 
     or Debug, then this could mean there was an error initializing logging 
     resources as well.
```

Apparently, [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd363790%28WS.10%29.aspx) is the solution, but I haven't the foggiest idea how to do what it asks.

There's some alternative solutions posted [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/b5d96f59-cd35-410f-8630-0577cc4c0f06), but in the case of Syct's answer, all the users/groups have permission levels equal to or greater than specified except that there is no user 'eventlog'. This may be the problem, but I don't know how to fix this and my Google-fu has failed me. Most of Miya Yao's answer is irrelevant to my scenario, but there is no location `Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\UserPnp` in the Event Viewer.

Any advice would be appreciated.